# Transition between field representation

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, finite-fields

In a number of papers related to efficient implementation of the AES Sbox, people are computing stuff (the multiplicative inverse for instance) in GF(($2^4$)$^2$) instead of GF($2^8$). In some cases they complicate it further by going down to GF(((($2^2$)$^2$)$^2$)...
My question is how do we find the transformation from one representation to the other and back ?

Examples of such paper freely available on the net:

["COMBINATIONAL LOGIC DESIGN FOR AES SUBBYTE TRANSFORMATION ON MASKED DATA" by ELENA TRICHINA](http://eprint.iacr.org/2003/236.pdf)

["A Very Compact S-box for AES" by D. Canright](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/011.pdf)

The field GF($2^8$) is defined by the irreducible polynomial fixed in the AES standard:
**m($x$) = $x^8$ + $x^4$ + $x^3$ + $x$ + 1**

The irreducible polynomial for the subfield can be chosen freely, for example, for GF(($2^4$)$^2$), a popular choice is
**n($x$) = $x^2$ + {1}$x$ + {e}**

From that they deduce a map function such that $a_h x + a_l = map(a), a_h , a_l$ ∈ GF ($2^4$ ), a ∈ GF ($2^8$ ) and the inverse function $map^-1$, but I have no clue about how they do, and how to verify if the result is right or not.

For **m($x$)** and **n($x$)** given as example, the following equations are the expected result:

$a_A = a_1 ⊕ a_7$
$a_B = a_5 ⊕ a_7$
$a_C = a_4 ⊕ a_6$
$a_l0 = a_C ⊕ a_0 ⊕ a_5$
$a_h0 = a_C ⊕ a_5$
$a_l1 = a_1 ⊕ a_2$
$a_h1 = a_A ⊕ a_C$
$a_l2 = a_A$
$a_h2 = a_B ⊕ a_2 ⊕ a_3$
$a_l3 = a_2 ⊕ a4$
$a_h3 = a_B$

Any pointer on a book which covers this problem is very welcome too^^

Comment: Your question is tedious to answer, because it uses a lot of non-standard notation - probably from the cited articles (thanks for the links!). For example, there is no standard meaning of the element $\{e\}$ (presumably from $GF(16)$. The the algebra is pretty basic, but details quickly become messy, as the size of the field grows => very few will want to say much about $GF((4^2)^2)$ :-). If no one else takes up on this, I will explain my understanding of the differences between implementing $GF(16)$ and $GF(4^2)$ tomorrow, and we can see how much that helps. Now - Shuteye time for me.

Comment: For sure an answer with "smaller" fields would be helpful, maybe even better to grab the general principles :-)

Comment: I added an answer that should help others that find this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to describe the passage between $GF(16)$ and $GF(4^2)$. The same principles can be applied in going from $GF(256)$ to $GF(16^2)$ and back.

Let us begin with $GF(4)$. It's elements are $0,1$, an element called $\alpha$ (aka the generator of the field) and $\alpha+1$. The arithmetic follows from the rule that $\alpha$ is a zero of the polynomial $x^2+x+1$, in other words $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$. In a program we represent the element
$a_1\alpha+a_0$ with the pair of bits $(a_1,a_0)$. So the individual bits are viewed as coefficients of a (at most linear) polynomial that we imagine to be evaluated at $\alpha$.

Similarly elements of $GF(16)$ are represented as sequences of bits $(a_3,a_2,a_1,a_0)$. This sequence represents the element $a_3\beta^3+a_2\beta^2+a_1\beta+a_0$, where $\beta$ is the (possibly, but hopefully not mysterious) generator. This time the arithmetic follows from the fact that $\beta$ is a zero of the polynomial $x^4+x+1$, in other words $\beta^4=\beta+1$. For example,
we then see that
$$
\beta^5=\beta\cdot\beta^4=\beta(\beta+1)=\beta^2+\beta, 
$$
and
$$
\beta^{10}=(\beta^5)^2=(\beta^2+\beta)^2=\beta^4+2\beta^2\beta+\beta^2
=\beta^4+\beta^2=\beta^2+\beta+1,
$$
using the fact that in all fields of characteristic two we have $2=1+1=0$. This piece of information is systematically used in a lot of software and hardware in the sense that field addition is implemented as bitwise XOR of the sequences representing the elements of the field.

We make the important observation that $\beta^2+\beta$ is a root of the same equation
$x^2=x+1$ as $\alpha$. This allows us to identify $GF(4)$ as a subset of $GF(16)$. We can choose to equate $\alpha=\beta^2+\beta$.

**Transformation from $GF(16)$ to $GF(4^2)$:** Consider an arbitrary element
$z=a_3\beta^3+a_2\beta^2+a_1\beta+a_0$ of $GF(16)$. We can get rid of the high powers of $\beta$ here using the equation $\beta^2+\beta=\alpha$, or rather the equivalent form
$\beta^2=\beta+\alpha$, and its consequence 
$\beta^3=\beta\cdot\beta^2=\beta(\beta+\alpha)=\beta^2+\alpha\beta=\alpha\beta+\beta+\alpha.$ Substituting these allows us to rewrite
$$
\begin{aligned}
z&=a_3(\alpha\beta+\beta+\alpha)+a_2(\beta+\alpha)+a_1\beta+a_0
=(a_3\alpha+[a_3+a_2+a_1])\beta+([a_3+a_2]\alpha+a_0)\\
&=a_h\beta+a_\ell,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $a_h=(a_3\alpha+[a_3+a_2+a_1])$ and $a_\ell=([a_3+a_2]\alpha+a_0)$ are elements of $GF(4)$. Internally we represent elements of $GF(4)$ with the sequence of coefficient of $\alpha^j,j=0,1$, e.g. $a_h=a_{h1}\alpha+a_{h0}$, so here
$$
a_{h1}=a_3,\quad a_{h0}=a_3+a_2+a_1,\quad a_{\ell1}=a_3+a_2,\quad a_{\ell0}=a_0.
$$

**Transformation from $GF(4^2)$ to $GF(16)$:** The other direction is also straightforward with the identification $\alpha=\beta^2+\beta$ in place. If we are given an element of 
$GF(4^2)$ in the form
$$
z=a_h\beta+a_\ell,
$$
where $a_h=a_{h1}\alpha+a_{h0}$ and $a_\ell=a_{\ell1}\alpha+a_{\ell0}$, then 
$$
\begin{aligned}
z&=(a_{h1}[\beta^2+\beta]+a_{h0})\beta+(a_{\ell1}[\beta^2+\beta]+a_{\ell0})\\
&=a_{h1}\beta^3+(a_{\ell1}+a_{h1})\beta^2+(a_{h0}+a_{\ell1})\beta+a_{\ell0}\\
&=z_3\beta^3+z_2\beta^2+z_1\beta+z_0,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $z_3=z_{h1}$, $z_2=(a_{\ell1}+a_{h1})$, $z_1=(a_{h0}+a_{\ell1})$ and
$z_0=a_{\ell0}$.

**Inversion in $GF(4^2)$:** Here the idea is to take advantage of the fact that inversion is easier in $GF(4)$ than it would be in $GF(16)$. Namely $1^{-1}, \alpha^{-1}=\alpha+1$
and $(\alpha+1)^{-1}=\alpha$. Equivalently $x^{-1}=x^2$ for any non-zero $x\in GF(4)$.
The idea is similar to inverting a complex number $z=x+yi$ where $x,y$ are real, at least one non-zero. There we make the observation that
$$
(x+yi)(x-yi)=x^2+y^2=Q(x,y),
$$
where we can deduce that the **real number** $Q(x,y)\neq0$. As we know how to compute the reciprocal of $Q(x,y)$ we can take advantage and compute
$$
\frac1{x+yi}=\frac1{Q(x,y)}(x-yi).
$$
The key to the success of such calculation is (this is bread and butter in field theory, but does
require a more extensive background in abstract algebra) that $i$ and $-i$
are roots of the same polynomial $x^2+1$ with real coefficients.

We can do something similar here. Remember that $\beta$ is a root
of the polynomial $x^2+x+\alpha$ with coefficients in $GF(4)$. The other root
of that polynomial is $\beta'=\beta+1$, because
$$
\beta'^2+\beta'=(\beta+1)^2+(\beta+1)=\beta^2+1+\beta+1=\beta^2+\beta=\alpha.
$$
So given an element $z=a_h\beta+a_\ell$ of $GF(4^2)$ let's calculate
$$
z(a_h\beta'+a_\ell)=a_h^2\beta\beta'+a_ha_\ell(\beta+\beta')+a_\ell^2.
$$
Here $\beta\beta'=\beta(\beta+1)=\beta^2+\beta=\alpha$ and $\beta+\beta'=1$, so we get
$$
z(a_h\beta'+a_\ell)=Q(a_h,a_\ll),
$$
where $Q(x,y)=\alpha x^2+xy+y^2$. Here we can prove that $Q(x,y)\neq0$
if at least one of $x,y$ is non-zero. If $x=0$, then $Q(x,y)=Q(0,y)=y^2\neq0$,
because then $y\neq0$. OTOH, if $x\neq0$, then
$$
Q(x,y)=\frac1{x^2}\left(\alpha+\frac{y}{x}+(\frac{y}{x})^2\right).
$$
Here the factor in round parens is $P(y/x)$, where $P(T)=T^2+T+\alpha$.
We have seen that $P(T)=0$, when $T=\beta$ or $T=\beta'$. Because $P(T)$ is
a quadratic polynomial it can have at most two zeros in the field $GF(16)$.
Because neither of those zeros was in the smaller field $GF(4)$ we can deduce that here
$P(y/x)\neq0$, because $y/x\in GF(4)$.

Putting all this together gives us, at long last,
$$
z^{-1}=\frac{1}{Q(a_h,a_\ell)}(a_h\beta'+a_\ell)
=\frac{1}{Q(a_h,a_\ell)}(a_h\beta+[a_h+a_\ell]).
$$
In other words, using the representation of $GF(16)$ as $GF(4^2)$
allows us to calculate the inverse in $GF(16)$ as a single inversion,
a single addition, and two multiplications in $GF(4)$. I guess that may be
worth the engineers' while in this setting.

**What is needed to extend this to conversion between $GF(256)$ and $GF(16^2)$:**
AES specifies that the field $GF(256)$ be given by using a generator $\theta$
that is a zero of the polynomial $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ [**EDIT Earlier I had another polynomial here. Corrected.**]. IOW the arithmetic of $GF(256)$ follows 
from the rule
$$
\theta^8=\theta^4+\theta^3+\theta+1.
$$
We need to identify a copy of $GF(16)$ inside that field. A little bit of tinkering
allowed me to find that 
$$
(\theta^{16}+\theta)=\theta^2+\theta^3+\theta^4+\theta^6
$$
is a solution of $x^4+x+1=0$. So let us declare 
$$\beta=\theta^2+\theta^3+\theta^4+\theta^6.$$
Then we can calculate that 
$${\bf\{e\}}=(1,1,1,0)_2=\beta^3+\beta^2+\beta=\theta^2+\theta^3+\theta^5+\theta^6+\theta^7.$$

It is possible to prove that
the polynomial $q(x)=x^2+x+{\bf\{e\}}$ has no solutions in $GF(16)$, and hence two in $GF(256)$.
The simplest proof of this relies on the properties of the trace mapping.

A little bit of searching reveals that the roots of $q(x)$ in $GF(256)$ are
$$
\gamma=\theta+\theta^2+\theta^3+\theta^4+\theta^5+\theta^6+\theta^7
$$
and 
$$\gamma+1=\gamma^{16}.$$
We can then represent
elements $z\in GF(256)$ in "$GF(16^2)$" format like
$$
z=a_h\gamma+a_\ell,
$$
where this time $a_h,a_\ell\in GF(16)$. The formula
for converting the 8-tuple of bits $(z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_7)$ to
the pair $(a_h,a_\ell)\in GF(16)^2$ such that
$$
z_0+z_1\theta+z_2\theta^2+\cdots+z_7\theta^7=z=a_h\gamma+a_\ell
$$
is quite messy, and I haven't calculated it.

Comment: Thanks very much the case for GF(16)<=>GF(4^2) is very clear. I also find the same solution θ6+θ3+θ2+θ with the polynomial x8+x4+x3+x2+1. But I don't find this polynomial in my references, nevermind, this is not the point.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand anything below $(\theta^{16}+\theta)=\theta^6+\theta^3+\theta^2+\theta$ :-S. Following the first example, I think I have to write z = $a_h$ $\beta^4$ + $a_l$, is it right ? if yes, how to get rid of other powers of $\beta$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, however I am still confused: Could you please clarify which polynomial is zero for $\gamma$  ? I don't really understand the sentence about $x^2+x+e$ having no solution in GF(16) and two in GF(256), could you elaborate on this ?

Comment: @acapola: Sorry to leave you hanging. I need to think about how the roots of $x^2+x+{e}$ can be found and used. I haven't forgotten about this, but have been busy elsewhere.

Comment: @acapola: I found the roots of $x^2+x+{e}$. I incorporated those bits to the end of my answer. Doesn't look "clean".

Comment: I fail to see that $\gamma=\theta+\theta^2+\theta^3+\theta^4+\theta^5+\theta^6+\theta^7$ is a root of $x^2+x+{e}$ in GF(256) with $x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1$ as primitive polynomial :-S I start with $x^2+x+\theta^2+\theta^3+\theta^5+\theta^6+\theta^7$ and I replace x by $\gamma$ : I get $\gamma^2+\theta^4+\theta$ and then $\theta^{14}+\theta^{12}+\theta^{10}+\theta^8+\theta^6+\theta^2+\theta$ then I reduce this modulo $\theta^8+\theta^4+\theta^3+\theta^2+1$ and get $\theta^7+\theta^6+\theta^5+\theta^4+1$ instead of 0. Can you tell me what is my error ?

Comment: I also don't see how you find the equivalence $\beta^3+\beta^2+\beta=\theta^2+\theta^3+\theta^5+\theta^6+\theta^7$ could you give me an hint about that too ?

Comment: @acapola: My answer suffered from a version coherence problem. Parts of the computations were done using the wrong minimal polynomial for $\theta$. Redoing  and checking my calculations.

Comment: It seems to me that I had simply forgotten to replace the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ with the correct polynomial even though I had done the calculations using the AES-polynomial. I (or rather Mathematica) still get the same roots for $q(x)$. It is somewhat infuriating that I couldn't figure out from the article that you linked, what the author means by the element ${\bf\{e\}}$ :-). The above is just my educated guess, and could easily be wrong. The expression for $\beta^3+\beta^2+\beta$ in terms of powers of $\theta$ was calculated using the AES polynomial all along.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is clear now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but this answer may be useful for others that find this question.

The two links in the question mention the method of sub-byte transformation also known as sub-field mapping, composite field mapping, field reduction, tower fields, ... , which has been used for Galois Field inversion (1/z) to reduce gate count in hardware implementations for Reed Solomon codes going back some time around 1990, perhaps prior to that. Link to a report from professor E J Weldon Jr to a tape company I worked for back then. The mapping in this report doesn't minimize gate count, but does reduce it compared to a hardware lookup table, and there was only one instance of an inverter, unlike an S box which could have 10 or more encoders + decoders in the same chip.

https://github.com/jeffareid/finite-field/blob/master/wldnrpt.pdf

In software, unless a field is very large, lookup tables can be used for inversion. For a software based $GF(2^8)$, a 256 byte table could be used, index by z with values 1/z in each entry of the table.

Getting back to the mapping, all Galois (finite) fields of the same size are isomorphic, but require mapping of elements between fields in order for the fields to be isomorphic in addition and multiplication:  map(a + b) = map(a) + map(b) and map(a b) = map(a) map(b). Typically, to map from $GF(2^8)$ to $GF((2^4)^2)$ or to $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$, an 8 row by 8 bit matrix is used to multiply an element of GF(2^8) treated as an 8 row by 1 bit matrix. The inverse matrix is used to map back to $GF(2^8)$.

The first link (Trichina) in the question uses polynomial basis. For example, each element of $GF((2^4)^2)$ is of the form $(a \ x \ + \ b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are elements of $GF(2^4)$, and $x$ is a variable in $GF((2^4)^2)$.

The second link (Canright) in the question uses normal basis. For example, each element of $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$ is of the form $(a \ Y^{16} \ + \ b \ Y)$, where $a$ and $b$ are elements of $GF((2^2)^2)$, and $Y$ is an element of $GF(2^8)$.

For polynomial basis, I have yet to find an article that explains how mapping matrices are created, so I explained this in the answer linked to below. Short version: the parameters (polynomials, primitive elements) for $GF((2^4)^2)$ or $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$ are chosen to minimize gate count. Generally $GF(2^8)$ polynomial is fixed, so the only variable is which of 128 possible primitive elements to use for the mapping. This is found by brute force trial and error search for a primitive element that will produce a isomorphic mapping matrix and its inverse. There are ways to optimize this for larger fields, but with only 128 possible candidates, there is no point in optimizing a one time search. The matrices are based on powers of primitive elements of the two fields. Link to an explanation:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3756361/327047

For normal basis, a brute force search is done for several parameters. I found an article that explains how mapping matrices are created. In that article, the matrix to map from $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$ to $GF(2^8)$ is determined first, and then its inverse produces the matrix to map from $GF(2^8)$ to $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$. The resulting matrices will be based on powers of primitive elements of the two fields. Link to an explanation:

[Normal basis on tower | composite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4647432/327047)

Comment: Glad to see you post here :-)