# composite field

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I wonder how to construct the irreducible polynomial of a composite field $GF((2^m)^n)$, where $q=mn$.

According to the example, the primitive polynomial of $GF(2^4)$ is $x^4 + x +1$. However, why the primitive polynomial of $GF((2^4)^2)$ is $x^2 + x + \{0 0 0 1\}$. Where the $\{ 0 0 0 1\}$ comes from?

Edit: Here presumably $\{0001\}$ lists the coordinates of an element of $GF(2^4)$ with respect to the basis consisting of powers $1,a,a^2,a^3$ where $a$ is a zero of $x^4+x+1$ (and hence a primitive element). In other words $\{0001\}=a^3$, JL

Comment: What is "the irreducible polynomial"? What is "the primitive polynomial"? What is "the example"? What is $\{0001\}$?

Comment: The example is from a book, "VLSI Architectures for modern error-correcting codes"

Comment: It is difficult to say for sure given that you won't tell us the meaning of $\{0001\}$. Anyway, my educated guess is that the meaning of the quoted passage matches with [this old answer of mine I prepared for referrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619). In the last part you see that the primitive polynomial $x^4+x+1$ factors of $GF(2^2)$ as 
$$x^4+x+1=(x^2+x+\beta)(x^2+x+\beta+1),$$ where $\beta$ and $\beta+1$ are the elements of $GF(4)$ that are not elements of $GF(2)$. The educated guess is therefore that $\{0001\}$ stands for one of them.

Comment: Mind you, I would never call this a *composite field* for that has a different technical meaning in field theory. Wouldn't be the first time a term is overloaded in algebra, though :-)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. According to my understanding is that {0001} is regarded as "a^3" where {1,a,a^2,a^3} is the standard basis of GF(2^4). I'm trying to know how they derive this primitive polynomial. What is the benefit of represent such a field in this way instead of GF(2^8)?

Comment: That makes some sense at least. I read it carelessly and thought that the question was about constructing $GF(2^4)$ as $GF((2^2)^2)$.

Comment: [This old related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167468/11619) may help. You see, constructing these fields as a tower of quadratic extensions is a rather esoteric exercise :-) My understanding is that it may have some benefits when implementing these fields with very limited pieces of hardware. Because I have never used such things, I'm a bit uncertain as to what the point is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\{0001\}$ truly stands for the element $\alpha^3$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4+x+1$, it follows that a zero $\beta$ of $x^2+x+\alpha^3$ is not a primitive element of $GF(256)$.

This is seen as follows. Recall that $\alpha$ is of order fifteen, so $\gamma:=\alpha^3$ is a fifth root of unity, and its minimal polynomial is $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. We have the relation
$$
\beta^2+\beta=\gamma.
$$
Squaring this three times and using $\gamma^5$ gives as consequences
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta^4+\beta^2&=\gamma^2,\\
\beta^8+\beta^4&=\gamma^4,\\
\beta^{16}+\beta^8&=\gamma^8=\gamma^3.
\end{aligned}
$$
Summing all these four equation gives us after cancellations on the left hand side
$$
\beta^{16}+\beta=\gamma+\gamma^2+\gamma^3+\gamma^4=1.
$$
So we can conclude that $\beta^{16}=\beta+1$
Multiplying this by $\beta$ gives
$$
\beta^{17}=\beta^2+\beta=\gamma.
$$
As $\gamma$ has order five, it follows that $\beta^{85}=1$, so $\beta$ is not a primitive element of $GF(256)$ (that would have to be of order $255$).

---

However, the polynomial $x^2+x+\gamma$ is irreducible over $GF(16)$. This is because $tr(\gamma)=1$, and this is exactly the well known irreducibility criterion. Therefore the field extension $GF(2)(\beta)=GF(256)$. If the author uses *primitive* in this sense (as opposed to in the standard finite field sense of *primitive*=*generator of the multiplicative group*), then the claim holds. But then the exercise would simply call you to prove that the quadratic $x^2+x+\gamma$ is irreducible, so this doesn't really hold water.

---

Unless I made a mistake, the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over the prime field is
$$
m(x)=x^8+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x+1.
$$

Comment: The drill with squaring is a standard trick of the trade. You see that I simply calculated the relative trace of $\beta$. And the answer is the coefficient of the linear term. An alternative way of arriving at $\beta^{17}=\gamma$ would be to use Vieta relations after proving that $x^2+x+\gamma$ is irreducible (which implies that its other root is the Frobenius conjugate $\beta^{16}$).